# How to apply metadata on tflite model?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api

I'm trying to launch TF Object detection Android app (https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android) with a custom model

I need to fix this issue

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images.
```

I found one suggestion, that I need to apply metadata on my .tflite model, so I tried to run

```
python tflite_convert.py \ --input_shapes="1,300,300,3" \ --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \ --output_arrays="TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3" \ --allow_custom_ops \ --saved_model_dir=alexey/saved_model \ --inference_input_type=FLOAT \ --inference_type=FLOAT \ --output_file=detect.tflite
```

And it was done without any errors, but when I launch the app with this generated .tflite I get the same error as without applying metadata.
So it seems to me that metadata was not applied

Comment: Refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata) doc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error today. [I solved it by running this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/metadata/metadata_writer_for_image_classifier.py). It generated a tflite and json file and I put both of them in the assets/models folder.

It's a good idea to just modify the flgs in the string than use command line parameters if you are on Windows 10 (just replace where it says none with the correct path)

Comment: Is there any similar script for meta data writer for audio classifiers?