# Unable to load my trained .tflite model also unable to calculate bounding boxes in android [Kotlin]

Tags: python, android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have .tflite trained model ( [**model-fp16.tflite**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nNyVA7TvBtSeBpSXbNeLfP5JPXCWWR1U/view?usp=sharing) ) in my android kotlin app, which I converted from yolov5.pt with this [repo](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) , but i'm unable to load my model.
getting this exception
 `org...lite.examples.objectdetection  E  Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images.`

My model properties are here in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h29ti.png) ,
i have tried many solutions and documentation of TensorFlow, but nothing happens,

i have tried [StackoverFlow Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446130/it-requires-specifying-normalizationoptions-metadata-to-preprocess-input-images) and [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488032/how-to-apply-metadata-on-tflite-model),
but nothing happens,
here are the lines where this error occurred

```
        val modelName = "model-fp16.tflite"

        try {
            objectDetector =
                ObjectDetector.createFromFileAndOptions(context, modelName, optionsBuilder.build())
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            objectDetectorListener?.onError(
                "Object detector failed to initialize. See error logs for details"
            )
            Log.e("Test", "TFLite failed to load model with error: " + e.message)
        }
```

i WANT to load my model and calculate detection results.

Thanks in advance.